# Close UIPickerView that is an UITextField inputview on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to close my UIPickerView when a selection was made:

```swift
    let pickerElement = UIPickerView()
    let textfieldElement = UITextField()

    textfieldElement.inputView = pickerElement
    pickerElement.delegate = self
    pickerElement.dataSource = self

    // ...
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textfieldElement.text = options[row].label as? String
        selectedElementId = options[row].id
        // this is not doing anything
        pickerElement.resignFirstResponder()
        pickerView.resignFirstResponder()
        
        // leaves the grey view open
        pickerElement.isHidden = true
        pickerView.isHidden = true
    }
```

This does not seem to work, it leaves open the grey view at the bottom:
[image]

Comment: try this textfieldElement.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to resign the text field instead of the picker or anything else.

Add this

```
textfieldElement.resignFirstResponder()
```

or you can also use

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Note: Remove all other things like resign to other views or hide.